# What are the plastic meals featured in restaurants called?

Tags: words, word-requests, food

I can point at the food that I would like to order, because there is a plastic representation of it. Is it called *purasuchikku shokuji*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [食品【しょくひん】サンプル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB) *shokuhin sanpuru*. (Also see the [大辞泉 entry via kotobank.jp](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB-678352#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89).)

Answer (score 0):

If you uttered "purasutiku shokuji" (it would more correctly be "purasuchikku" or プラスチック) in the right context you could make yourself understood, but 食品サンプル ("shouhin sanpuru") is definitely the right term. Also, those models are sometimes made of other materials different from plastic, such as wax.

Comment: The question has been amended.